# Aligning text using Tabularize

Tags: vim

I'm using the Tabularize plugin in Vim and have the following text:

```
reg [321:123] ip_addr=32'h12345678;
reg [15:0] trie_data=16'h9abc;
reg [2:0] select=3'h5;

wire [3:0] nibble;
wire sram_bit;
```

which I want to align in this manner:

```
reg  [321:123] ip_addr   = 32'h12345678;
reg   [15:0]   trie_data = 16'h9abc;
reg    [2:0]   select    = 3'h5;

wire   [3:0]   nibble;
wire           sram_bit;
```

In words:

- left-align reg/wire in first column
- center-align bit-widths, if present, along ':'
- left-align signal names in third column
- = signs in the 4th column
- left-align initial values in 5th column.

So far, I've tried the following in order:

```
:Tabularize /[[0-9]*:/l1r0l0
:Tabularize /:[0-9]*]/l0l1l0
:Tabularize /=
```

but this combines 'wire' and 'sram_bit' in the first column instead of putting it in the first and third column respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two Tabularize commands it can be done like this

```
:Tabularize /[[0-9]*:/l1c0l0
:Tabularize /=
```

So here you basically use `[number:` as the delimiter.

Comment: Bernhard, it almost worked. However, the last line was left out; it put wire sram_bit together in the first column. `l1c0l0` will work in this case but it'd fail if my starting index was 3 digits. 
Thanks for getting me started; I've edited my question to include this case.

Comment: Your example works well for me on the first three lines. The laat last line does not fit to the tabular format that Tabularize needs. I don't see a nice way to do this with Tabularize.

Answer (score 1):

Or with Align.vim

```
:AlignCtrl <>
:AlignCtrl p0
:%Align \S\+

:AlignCtrl p1
:%Align =
```

I have the feeling that there should be a simple way to combine those, but I didn't quite figure it out at once, so I'll leave it for another day

Comment: Hello Sehe, I want to know how to do it with Tabularize.vim but thanks for responding :)